# Issue with regular expression for string validation

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to validate following type of string using regular expressions in PHP. Using PHP 5.5.9.

String is in following format:

```
/[sometext]/course/[sometext1]/[sometext2]
```

What I need is a regex that will accept string that is only in that format and nothing else. Meaning these would be invalid:

```
/aaa/course/bbb/ccc/
/aaa/course/bbb/ccc/ddd
```

What I have so far is this:

```
/\/(?P<domain>.+?)\/course\/(?P<courseid>.+?)\/(?P<reportname>.+?)/
```

Any ideas?

Update:

With the help from all posters and especially wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew I got this one that works:

```
 $regex = '#^/(?P<domain>[^/]+)/course/(?P<courseid>[^/]+)/(?P<reportname>[^/]+)$#';
```

Comment: 1) Used negated character class, 2) Use anchors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
^\/(?P<domain>[^\/]+)\/course\/(?P<courseid>[^\/]+)\/(?P<reportname>[^\/]+)$
```

PHP:

```
$re = '~^/(?P<domain>[^/]+)/course/(?P<courseid>[^/]+)/(?P<reportname>[^/]+)$~';
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uD7kE9/2)

The `[^\/]` is a negated character class that matches any character but `/`.

The `^` and `$` are usually enough to make sure your input starts and ends with the current pattern (you can replace them with `\A` and `\z` respectively to make sure the `\z` matches at the very end of the string, or use `^`/`$` with the `/D` modifier).

Even if you use lazy `.+?` dot matching, the `.` can overflow several `/` delimiters if it is necessary to return a valid match.

Comment: This looks promising. What about named group values? I would also prefer those.

Comment: I added them, sorry, was busy with another answer.

Answer (score 1):

first... use something other than '/' as your delimiter (the slashes as the beginning and end of the regex)...  it makes it easier to write the regex without having to escape the delimiter within

```
$regex = '#^/[a-z]+/[^/]+/[a-z]+/[a-z]+$#'
```

Comment: This regex will fail if there is a digit inside and matches strings without `/course/`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  yes... but is it supposed to match alphanumeric, numeric, alpha-only?   anything sans "/"?   nobody knows except the OP

Comment: OP can't know that either, that is why negated chwracter class is required here. See  my answer for details.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  cool... I used [^/] for the course segment...  I infered from his examples that the other 3 segments were alpha-only

Comment: :-) Those are mere placeholders.